# My minimise, maximise and close buttons have dissapeared!

Tags: helpfile

I've somehow managed to get ride of my minimise, maximise and close button on my laptop. I use google chrome at the moment, but it's on all my programmes, not just on chrome - any help?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type:

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/button_layout --type string :minimize,maximize,close
```

Comment: I think penreturn means to say: gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/button_layout --type string :minimize,maximize,close The change being "button", rather than "buttom". Sorry, couldn't edit the post with only one character change.

Comment: I fixed his text.

Answer (score 0):

To get my minimize, maximize and close button on my laptop (I use google chromium on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail), I simply move my cursor onto the grey bar at the top and the buttons magically appear along with File, Edit, View, History, Tools & Help.
I hope this helps.
Regards
Jim.